# Lost all desktop icons

Tags: ubuntu-mate, desktop-icons

I was cleaning my keys and I managed to lose all of my desktop icons.

One of those keys was the space bar.

I also can not add any new programs to the desktop.

When I right click on the desktop, nothing appears.

The desktop directory has those programs.

How can I fix my mess?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went into Mate Tweak and checked Show Desktop Icons.

Comment: OK... so, lesson learned: Don't clean your keyboard with the computer on; it sends tons of weird key combinations, and you might not like the result. ;-)